# Solving constants in a contradiction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So, this is a really simple question, but I really can't find an answer for this. If I have an equation $3x - ax + 5 = 3$, how can I find out which value of constant $a$ will cause the equation be always false? Sorry if I'm just stupid.

Comment: Can you eliminate $x$ entirely with the right choice of $a$?

Comment: What happens if $a=3?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$3x - ax + 5 =3$$
$$(3-a)x =-2$$
$$y\cdot x = -2$$
What value of $y$ will make it so that $y \cdot x = -2$ will ***never*** be true, no matter what $x$ is?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me get it down on paper.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $y= 3x-ax + 5$ is always a line, and $y=3$ is also a line, what have to happen for two lines to no cut each oder?

Comment: yes thank you, this helped, but I think the algebraic form above was a bit mroe helpful.

Answer (score 1):

$3x-ax+5=3\implies x(3-a)=-2\implies x=-\frac2{3-a}$.  So we cannot have $a=3$.

Comment: yep thanks, this was also helpful. I have a good understanding of the idea now.

Answer (score 0):

$ 3x - ax + 5 = 3 $

$ 3(x-a) = -2 $

$ x - a = \frac{-2}{3} $

"a" is contradicting when $ a \neq \frac{3x+2}{3}, x  \ \forall \ \mathbb{R}. $